# How to tuck divs under with Bootstrap where there is a long div?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

Need `new div` to tuck in underneath `oldie`, so `tall div` is long on the right.

```
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 ">oldie</div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
          <div class="tall">rightie</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12">new div</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Code Pen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPgbbx)

Then make sure that in mobile view The order is:

```
oldie
rightie
new div
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible in Bootstrap unless you duplicate the contents of *new div*.

The one for the small screen should get the class `.hidden-md` and `.hidden-lg` to hide them on `md` and `lg` screens. The one for the large screen should be a nested grid together with the *oldie* div and get the class `.hidden-xs` and `.hidden-sm` to be hidden on `xs` and `sm` screens.

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #c66;
  background-color: #f99;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.box--tall {
  height: 250px;
  line-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 box">oldie</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 box hidden-xs hidden-sm">new div</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 box box--tall">
      rightie
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 box hidden-md hidden-lg">
      new div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```